# Write reusable template part django

Tags: django

In my templates, in many places, I've got repeating parts, like:

```
       <th class="column-title">
        <a href="?{% query_transform order_by='x' %}">
            {{ objForm.x.label_tag }}</a>
       </th>
       <th class="column-title">
        <a href="?{% query_transform order_by='y' %}">
            {{ objForm.y.label_tag }}</a>
       </th>
       <th class="column-title">
        <a href="?{% query_transform order_by='z' %}">
            {{ objForm.z.label_tag }}</a>
       </th>
```

Is there a way, to write some "function" to render such html part like: (pseudocode)

in html:

```
render("x")
render("y")
render("z")
```

in python:

```
def render(param):
   return " <th class="column-title">
        <a href="?{% query_transform order_by='+param+' %}">
            {{ objForm'+param+'.label_tag }}</a>
       </th>"
```

PS. I know, that theoreticaly I can prepare ordered list in view, and then iterate over it in a template, but I think it is not a good solution ,as I prefer to build my view, fields order etc on the template side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [include template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) to insert your common template code where you need it.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        {% include "table_header.html" with field=objForm.x %}
        {% include "table_header.html" with field=objForm.y %}
        {% include "table_header.html" with field=objForm.z %}
    <tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

and

```
<a href="?{% query_transform order_by=field.name %}">
    {{ field.label_tag }}
</a>
```

Comment: Hi, that's what I needed. Thanks. The only problem now is, with nested tags, ie.  {{ objForm.{{param}}.label_tag }}   causes error...   /?

Comment: @andrew Split it into multiple parameters, e.g. {% include "table_header.html" with order_by="x" label_tag=objForm.x.label_tag %}

Comment: ok @domininique  it should work, thanks again. However, the solution is not as clean as I desired :)  Maybe any other ideas, guys ??

Comment: @andrew I updated the answer to use the field object rather than the string name. Is that what you are looking for as cleaner?